# Open google doc alternateLink with certain user

Tags: google-drive-api

I am developing a google docs web app. When I open a file in google drive by getAlternateLink(), If user have login google with his account, will popup a window ask permission. But I do not want user use his google account. In other words, I want to assign a google account for this user, then open file with the google account that I created. How can do this. The user should do not know which google account belong to him.

Answer (score 0):

Use service accounts, you can create files with an service account and authenticate the request without any user interaction. https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts

Comment: But looks service accounts can not purchase additional Google Drive storage. And I want each account own its storage